# Why do I get a "potential resource leak" warning with a wrapping writer object?

Tags: java, eclipse, resources, warnings

I have Eclipse issue the following warning:

> `Potential resource leak: '<unassigned Closeable value>' may not be closed`

...for the expression `new BufferedWriter(...)` in the snippet below:

```
boolean useStdout = askUserWhetherToUseStdout();
Writer writer = useStdout ? new OutputStreamWriter(System.out) : new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(askUserForFilename())));
try {
    writer.write("Hello World!");
}
finally {
    writer.close();
}
```

Is this a false positive? The way I have understood the whole `Writer` thing is that any writer will close its underlying writers. In my case, `writer` will encapsulate the new buffered writer (which in turn encapsulates a file writer), and so closing `writer` should not leak any resources associated with the buffered writer or its underlying writers?

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

*Edited answer based on updated question:*

It's a bogus warning - based on the use of the ternary operator. If the right hand side of operation does not fire then the `BufferedWriter` is not going to be created, and there is no resource leak. So what the warning describes is really not a possibility. However, if you wanted to 'handle' it, just move the creation of the writer inside your try block.

```
boolean useStdout = askUserWhetherToUseStdout();
Writer writer = null;
try {
    writer = useStdout ? new OutputStreamWriter(System.out)
            : new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(
                    askUserForFilename())));
    writer.write("Hello World!");
} finally {
    if (writer != null)
        writer.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you but actually, I forgot to add `try` and `catch` in my example, as they are in the original code. The warning has nothing to do with IOException. I still get the warning, you see..

Comment: If the thread your code runs in is killed prior to executing the finally block, the finally block might never get executed, while your app still continues running. Dunno if try-with-resource covers this case, but it seems likely.

Answer (score 1):

If `writer.write("Hello World!");` throws an Exception, `writer.close()` is never called.

Try wrapping it into a try-catch block (probably making use of the auto-closing feature, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: Thank you but actually, I forgot to add `try` and `catch` in my example, as they are in the original code. The warning has nothing to do with IOException. I still get the warning, you see..

Answer (score 1):

Could you check if this code gives you warning? If not then you probably didn't handle IOException while creating writer which should also be done in try block.

```
boolean useStdout = askUserWhetherToUseStdout();
Writer writer = null;
try {
    writer = useStdout ? new OutputStreamWriter(System.out)
            : new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(
                    askUserForFilename())));
    writer.write("Hello World!");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (writer != null)
            writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You can also use try-with-resources which will automatically close resource stream after try block.

```
boolean useStdout = askUserWhetherToUseStdout();
try (Writer writer = useStdout ? new OutputStreamWriter(System.out)
        : new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(
                askUserForFilename())))) {
    writer.write("Hello World!");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```